Chroma sqlite dependency conflict when deploying flask server on render
I have a flask server that I'm trying to deploy on render and every time I do so, I'm encountering this issue: "Error: Your system has an unsupported version of sqlite3. Chroma                 requires sqlite3 >= 3.35.0." I am aware there is documentation available through Chroma's official website, including various other stack overflow and github forums regarding how to solve it, which I've looked at to try and debug this issue but am stuck on how to move past this. I have tried the following so far:

Based on Chroma's official troubleshooting guide, I verified that my python version is >= 3.10. To be precise it is 3.11.5
pip install pysqlite3-binary doesn't work since I'm not on a linux system. I'm using a 2023 M2 macbook pro for reference purposes.
Based on this guide I tried downgrading Chroma, my current version being 0.5.5 to 0.3.29 but that also didn't work. I also tried downgrading my chromadb version from 0.5.5 to a bit of a lower but higher one than 0.3.29 like 0.5.3 which required me to update chroma-hnswlib as well to 0.7.3 but that also didn't work because it threw the same version error as mentioned earlier
As suggested by many forums, I tried adding this to the top of the file containing all my flask server logic: __import__('pysqlite3') import sys sys.modules['sqlite3'] = sys.modules.pop('pysqlite3') and I even verified that when running sqlite3 --version it is 3.46.0 which is greater than 3.35.0 but this too didn't help.

At this point, I'm just stuck on how to proceed with solving this and would greatly appreciate any insights regarding this because my system clearly has the correct python and sqlite version but when deploying the app on render it isn't getting picked up for some reason.
